# Gtest does not write result xml file on test failure [jenkins]

Tags: ios, jenkins, googletest

I invoke our gtest suite for iOS in Jenkins using the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -a "iPhone Simulator"
ios-sim launch ${WORKSPACE}/source/apple/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppTest.app --args --gtest_output=xml:${WORKSPACE}/JUnitTestResultsIOS.xml

exit $?
```

This always successfully runs the tests, and when the tests pass the xml file gets generated as expected. However, when the tests fail, no xml file is generated, and the "Execute shell command" build step terminates but does not fail the job. I echoed the exit code and it comes back 0 even when the tests fail.

This is even more confusing to me since we have a basically identical script in the same job for running tests on our OSX version. This always writes the xml and successfully fails the job when the tests fail.

This behavior seems totally arbitrary and everything about our configuration seems to be exactly as it should be. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two things at work here.

First of all, we had the break_on_failure gtest option enabled, which works great when running tests on a local machine but isn't useful within Jenkins, so we disabled it on the build machine.

The second issue was around how we used the exit code. Since `ios-sim launch ...` always succeeds we were always getting an exit code of 0, regardless of whether the tests passed or failed. I ended up using `grep` to determine if the resulting xml file indicated any failures, and generated an exit code based on that.